# passing variable from VB function to client side javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

hello i am using this Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() to call a  javascript function  from vb code behind , and this works fine with me My question is how can i send variables from the code behind to the javascript function here is what i have tried so far :

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Handles Me.LoadComplete
    Dim Myname As String = "myName"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "MyKey", "hello(Myname);",
  True)

End Sub
```

javascript :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(name) {
        alert("hello world from javascript " + name)
    }
</script>
```

Thank you ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use correct quotations to pass strings:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Handles Me.LoadComplete
    Dim Myname As String = "myName"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "MyKey", "hello('" & Myname & "');",
  True)

End Sub
```

Note single quotes around variable name.

Another way for bi-directional passing of data between client and server-side code is hidden fields, e.g

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="xhidMyname" runat="server" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" id="xhidMyname" runat="server" />
```

This field will be accessible both client-side and server side via it's "value" property.

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Handles Me.LoadComplete
    Dim Myname As String = "myName"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "MyKey", "hello('"&Myname&"');",
  True)

End Sub
```

Comment: ya, sorry I missed to add single quote around the string